# Will .Net's Bitmap.Save method always produce same BMP file with the proper PixelFormat setting

Tags: .net, image, process, bmp

I need to load some image files and convert it to certain format of BMP files. The system is made up of a C# PC application and a embedded application.

After conversion, the PC application downloads the converted image to flash and the embedded application will dynamically load and display it.

The image format used by the embedded system is basically 16bpp BMP with slight differences in its header part.

Because lack of memory, I hope the `Bitmap` object in the embedded application can point to the pixel array of the BMP in flash directly without any conversion on its side. So I need to do some work on PC side.

Here my question is there are lots of different varieties of BMP file formats, mainly the header part. Can I guarantee the `Bitmap.Save` will give me the same result no matter what kind input image it was given?

What I have done now is I create a `Bitmap` class and set the pixel format as `16bpp565` and save it as BMP files. Is this way safe?

For example a 16bpp BMP file can have an optional color table. How can I gurantee the BMP file I create without one.

Comment: For example a 16bpp BMP file can have an optional color table. How can I gurantee the BMP file I create without one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A 16bpp bitmap cannot have a palette (aka color table).  It would be far too large.  Note the missing "Indexed" format in the PixelFormat enumeration.  The Bitmap class already uses a memory mapped file, the odds that you could improve on that are very slim.

Comment: I think you can rely on this. But I would create a test app (that will test format of resulting files on PC) and run on several hudreds of images, to see, that everything works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.